# could numpy.random.poisson be used to add poisson noise to images?

Tags: image, image-processing, numpy, noise

For every pixle of one  image,I have its x(int),y(int) and pixel value(float number).

Now I need to add noise to the image.Is numpy.random.poisson appropriate?

I am worried about it because it is not like  new pixle value=original value+noise,but like

new pixle value=numpy.random.poisson(original value,1) .And the new values are all integers.

My question is as the title.

My purpose is to get a photometry measurement error for a star.But I have only one iamge.So I do a simulation via adding poisson noise. 
Please check the figure got from the ccd image below.The source is the red feature.

[image]

Comment: well, yes is the simple answer. But what are the statistics of your noise? Is it multivariate (probably not if you're trying to model e.g. shot noise)? What is the dynamic range of your image?

Comment: we got one CCD image for a light source.Now we need to make synthetic data via adding noise.It should be poisson noise.The lowest value in the image is about 4700,while the highest is 30000.But I just care about the source.The pixel values are between 5000 to 5100 in a box region covering the source. After removing the background,the pixel values may be around 80 to 100.My concern is the source is faint and is in a bright background.In fact,the noise added may be lighter than the source itself.

Comment: The noise might well be brighter than the image! If you try to take a photo with a digital camera in low light, the images are often pretty noisy (albeit generally having been thoroughly jpegged). I don't really understand what you're trying to do - perhaps you could give some more detail in the question. Perhaps with a miniature synthetic dataset and showing what you want to do and the problems with it.

Comment: I have updated my post.PLease check it.BTW,how do mean by dynamical range?It is just as simple as the wikipedia says?Let me take my chance.You ever used ds9(http://hea-www.harvard.edu/RD/ds9/site/Home.html)? It can display a fits image.The source is faint but I can adjust the scale in ds9 to make the source emerge.That means the dynamical range has been changed?

Comment: So you want to create a synthetic version of the image you have above? The dynamic range is what Wikipedia says it is. Are you saying the statistics of the noise are derived from the image? Or something else? Is this multiplicative noise? Is the following correct...? you have a very faint image of a star which is derived from a small number of incident photons, so the data is encoded within the noise statistics? (and presumably buried in shot noise as well?)

Comment: yes,I plan to make many synthetic iamges.The new pixel value is numpy.random.poisson(original value,1). Every new value is only dependent on the only pixel value on the only original image.You are right.You can see the star is buried in a bright background,but we can say there is a star there.The feature is obvious.In order to get a photometry error,I will make synthetic data sets.Maybe I can make the 1sigma photometry value as the photometry error?

Comment: I guess so. The issue here is not really one for SO but to do with the model you need to use. I'm not sufficiently familiar with the physics of the imaging system to give you a definitive answer, but using your smooth image as the lambda values seems like a plausible thing to be doing. Why not ask a question on [astronomy.stackexchange.com](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) or [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.I did not know those particular sites before.Forgive my retard.What do you mean by SO and lambda value?You suggest I add noise(same method,from the original image) to the smoothed image,not to the original image?

Comment: No, I suggest that perhaps you use the original image (or each sample of the original image) as the parameter, lambda, of the Poisson distribution. This is the first argument of `numpy.random.poisson`. It's up to you to establish that this is a sensible thing to do as regards the physics, but I would consider that as a good starting point for discussion. Also, SO=StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes,I agree with you.It is a monte-carlo test to get the error.It is reasonable ,right?

Comment: `skimage.util.random_noise(im, 'poisson')` should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old thread, but I know the answer to this, so here goes.

The answer is yes.

```
imageplusshotnoise = numpy.random.poisson(lam=<noiseless_simulated_image>, size=None)
```

This will produce a sample image from a Poisson distribution for each pixel of the original image.  Poisson distributions have a special property where the mean and the variance are equal.  This means that if the mean is say 100 counts that the variance will be 100; hence, the shot noise will have a standard deviation of 10 (variance is equal to the standard deviation squared).

Create a numpy image array with all the values equal to 100

```
>>> myimage = 100 * np.ones((100,100))
>>> np.mean(myimage)
100.0
>>> np.std(myimage)
0.0
```

Note that the mean is 100 and the standard deviation is 0 as expected

Now using this image as the lambda of a Poisson distribution will produce a sample from that distribution with the same size

```
>>> imageplusnoise = np.random.poisson(lam=myimage, size=None)
>>> imageplusnoise.shape
(100, 100)
```

The mean of the sample will have the same mean as the lambda, but the standard deviation will be equal to the sqrt of the variance, which in a Poisson distribution is equal to the mean.

```
>>> np.mean(imageplusnoise)
100.0474
>>> np.std(imageplusnoise)
10.015934965843179
```

To obtain only the shot noise, simple subtract lambda from it and now the mean will be close to zero (if the mean is small, the mean noise will start skewing further from zero), but it will always have the same standard deviation.

```
>>> noiseonlyimage = imageplusnoise - myimage
>>> np.mean(noiseonlyimage)
0.047399999999999998
>>> np.std(noiseonlyimage)
10.015934965843179
```

It should be pointed out here that the lam argument is the expectation value of the Poisson distribution and is noiseless.  Your starting image looks like it already has noise, so I would start out by modeling the star response through your aperture to obtain the noiseless image say using some point spread function like an airy disk, sinc function or similar as the input to the numpy.random.poisson function.